# Will removing the return leg from a traveling salesman problem ever change the results?

Tags: combinatorics

In a typical traveling salesman problem one starts at an origin point, visits a number of points once, then returns to the origin point in the most efficient way possible.

Are there any scenarios in which removing the requirement to return to the origin point at the end of the journey would change the optimal route through the rest of the stops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

[image]

[image]

In fact four points are enough: $A,C,D,F$ in this example.

Comment: Thanks, seems so obvious now..!